# RAM usage of SQL CE database in .NET CF

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am writing a windows mobile application on C# and .NET CF that uses a large amount of data which is stored currently in RAM. Due to the virtual memory limitation in windows CE, I need to reduce the RAM usage. I was wondering if using a SQL CE database and storing the data in the database will reduce the RAM usage.
So, basically I need to know when a SQL CE database is used, whether the data is stored on disk or on RAM.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Also have a look at SQLite. This also works for mobile and has a far smaller footprint.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Compact is going to use a file as a backing store.  Will that reduce RAM usage? That greatly depends on how you're doing things now and how you use the SQL Compact database.

If you put the SDF file in a persistent store, then it will take up less RAM for storage.  If you put everything in one table and then use something like a DataTable to hold the results from "SELECT * FROM MyTable" then the entire thing would get replicated into RAM, removing any benefit.  If, however, you use SQL statements to filter the returned data, then memory usage will decrease.  Using ResultSets and DataReaders instead of giant DataSets makes a large difference as well.

So can it reduce your memory usage?  Probably, provided you use the database engine to look at small parts of the data at a time.  Again, it all depends on what you're doing now, though, for a comparison.